# Publish to facebook page as page not as user message works link not

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-php-sdk, publish

I'm using php-sdk and everything goes fine when i'm publishing to fan page only the text message, it appears as fanpage post... when i'm posting link with the same function it appears as user post ... why?

```
try {
      $res = $facebook->api('/'.$PAGE_ID.'/feed', 'POST',                   
                  array(
                        'access_token' => $PAGE_ACCESS_TOKEN
                        ,'message' => $message                        
                        ,'link' => $link
                      ) 
            );                       } catch (FacebookApiException $e) 
     {
        echo "e:".$e->getMessage();
        var_dump($res);
     }
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to post to the page as the page itself, you must use the access token for the page instead of the user.

Go an API call to `/me/accounts` and you will see a list of pages / apps the user has access to. Each entry will have a `access_token` providing the user has accepted 'manage_pages` permission.

Using this `access_token` in your API call will let you publish as the page.

Comment: Its working! Thanks. And maybe You know how to remove the application name from the post? "page name" published by "app name" ?

Comment: You won't be able to remove the app name from the post.